# Gemara on volunteering?

Tags: talmud-gemara, employment, sources-mekorot, quotations

I heard that there was a Gemara to the effect of "volunteers cost more than employees because their motivation is not as good" -- or somesuch. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're thinking of Bava Kamma 85a: "A doctor who heals for nothing [i.e., without pay] is worth nothing."

Comment: Alex, I just skimmed the daf, so maybe I missed it, but where does it say that? Also, it's talking about how much someone is obligated to pay for damages, so couldn't that be simply saying "Why does he have to pay Refuah, when he could find a free doctor? No, a doctor who heals for nothing is worth nothing," meaning that a person has a right to see a competent doctor who charges reasonable fees over a quack if he so chooses?

Comment: @SethJ: near the bottom of the amud: אסיא דמגן במגן מגן שוה. You're right that the context is the victim's right to proper medical care, but I don't think the suggestion is that the free doctor would necessarily be a quack; Rashi says that the assailant might have a relative (who'd be willing to do him a favor).

Comment: Thanks for point it out.  I'm not sure what you're saying, though.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, but it doesn't sound like the right one. The prof was commenting that volunteers are often more trouble than employees due to lack of monetary motivation, lack of training etc. He said there was a Gemara on it.